# Excel: Checking for matching values between sheets

Tags: excel

I have two Excel spreadsheets. One (SheetA) has 6000+ rows and 20+ columns of data, the other (sheetB) has ~700 rows and ~10 columns. The ~700 entries on SheetB should all appear on SheetA as well. SheetB has updated information on certain entries from SheetA and I want to crosscheck the information to make sure it all matches. I need to compare the values listed for the variable "Counties" on SheetB against the values on SheetA, using the variable "SiteID". In other words, I want to make sure that for every SiteID on SheetB, the corresponding SiteID on SheetA has the same values listed for Counties.

As a sample:

SheetA

```
Site ID         Country
123XXX          Smith
124XXX          Doe
125XXX          Smith
```

SheetB

```
SideID          Country
123XXX          Doe
124XXX          Doe
```

SiteID 123XXX has different values between SheetA and SheetB; I want to flag this. SiteID 124XXX has the same values; this is fine. SiteID 125XXX does not appear in SheetB; I can ignore this. what I need to do is flag the inconsistencies and fix them on SheetA.

Comment: You can do this with Conditional Formatting,  Using a COUNTIFS() formula.

Comment: Agree, although OP needs to clarify if it's the position or contents of the mismatch(es) that is needed, or just the fact that there is (at least) one.

Comment: Position and contents, if possible

Comment: What is the problem though ? - it would help to explain what's preventing you from doing this.

Comment: Simply that I don't know the most efficient way to compare the data in bulk. I recognize I sound quite dense and I'm confident there's a way to do this, I just don't know it.

Comment: On SheetB add a column and use VLOOKUP() against SheetA to pull back the Country for the matching SiteId and compare that with the value on SheetB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has been practically answered in the comments, but for the record to count the number of mismatches, put this in SheetB!C2:-

```
=COUNTIFS(SheetA!A$1:A$10,A2,SheetA!B$1:B$10,"<>"&B2)
```

You can't just use a VLOOKUP or MATCH to find the first matching Site ID on SheetA and compare the country with SheetB because the first matching Site ID might match on column B but there could be further occurrences of the same Site ID that don't match i.e. you have this situation:-

[image]

But you could use this array formula in (say) SheetB!D2 to find the first mismatching country for a given Site ID:-

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(1,(SheetA!A$1:A$10=A2)*(SheetA!B$1:B$10<>B2),0),"")
```

To find the contents, you could add an INDEX function to this in SheetB!E2:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SheetA!B$1:B$10,MATCH(1,(SheetA!A$1:A$10=A2)*(SheetA!B$1:B$10<>B2),0)),"")
```

Need to enter the previous two formulae using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

But having said all this, maybe it makes more sense just to highlight the ones in SheetA that differ from SheetB using a COUNTIFS formula in conditional formatting?

It's also possible to list the position & contents of multiple mismatches but I would use a bit of VBA to do this.

Excel doesn't have a concatenation function that's very useful, but you can use a published function like [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/stringconcatenation.aspx) which gives you

```
=stringconcat(",",IF((SheetA!A$1:A$10=A2)*(SheetA!B$1:B$10<>B2),ROW(SheetA!A$1:A$10),""))
```

for the position of multiple matches

and this for the contents:-

```
=stringconcat(",",IF((SheetA!A$1:A$10=A2)*(SheetA!B$1:B$10<>B2),SheetA!B$1:B$10,""))
```

No guarantees for how fast this would be but probably OK on 6,000 rows.

Footnote - I thought maybe having a country called Smith was a bit unusual, but there is a list [here](http://sarathc.com/countries-named-after-people.html) of several countries named after people - and there are plenty of people named after countries :-)